# SSIS package is failing."Failed to clean up. The proxy created for the Web service might not have been deleted."

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, proxy, package

I have created a duplicate of the package in our Dev Environment and for that I checked the "Use Proxy" because it would not work with out it. Now the original package in our Production environment is failing with the that error. The original Package is working when ran from our server but when ran as a Job it fails with that error. The new package in the Dev Environment is working. No idea what is going on. I removed the proxy setting for the Dev package and am now waiting to see if it is fixed. Any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This type issue is occurs because when you are running your package at `Dev environment` then you have all the access but when you run your package through job at `Production server` then you don't have sufficient `access` to run the job by your logins.
So better you have to call `DBA` and ask him to change the `job owner` for that particular job.
Same issue occurred with me so I have take the help of `DBA` and change the job owner,Actually when you create job at `Dev environment` then it's by your `logins` but at product you don't have access to run or modified a job.